# How to arrange admin menu order in wordpress dashbooard

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to re-arrange the menu order in my wordpress admin dashboard and tried the following code. But could not be succeeded. Below the code i used. I used them in the functions.php page.

```
function enable_custom_menu_order() {
return true;
    }

function custom_menu_order() {
//return array('edit.php','shashopping.php', 'edit-comments.php','index.php' );
return array( 
'admin.php?page=my_plugin_page.php',    //my plugin page
'tools.php', // Tools  
    'index.php', // Dashboard
    'separator1', // First separator
    'admin.php',
    'edit.php', // Posts  
    'upload.php', // Media  
    'link-manager.php', // Links  
    'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages  
    'edit-comments.php', // Comments  
    'separator2', // Second separator  
    'themes.php', // Appearance  
    'plugins.php', // Plugins  
    'users.php', // Users
    'options-general.php', // Settings  
    'separator-last', // Last separator  

  );  
  }

 add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'enable_custom_menu_order' );
 add_filter( 'menu_order', 'custom_menu_order' );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to customize the admin menu order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655488/unable-to-customize-the-admin-menu-order)

Answer (score 2):

Download the file to drop in your theme's directory here: [wp-admin-menu-classes.php](https://gist.github.com/792b7aa5b695d1092520) and then you might call the functions in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
 <?php
    require_once('wp-admin-menu-classes.php');
    add_action('admin_menu','my_admin_menu');
    function my_admin_menu() {
      swap_admin_menu_sections('Pages','Posts');              // Swap location of Posts Section with Pages Section
      rename_admin_menu_section('Media','Photos & Video');    // Rename Media Section to "Photos & Video"
      delete_admin_menu_section('Links');                     // Get rid of Links Section
      $movie_tags_item_array = get_admin_menu_item_array('Movies','Movie Tags');  // Save off the Movie Tags Menu
      update_admin_menu_section('Movies',array(               // Rename two Movie Menu Items and Delete the Movie Tags Item
        array('rename-item','item'=>'Movies','new_title'=>'List Movies'),
        array('rename-item','item'=>'Add New','new_title'=>'Add Movie'),
        array('delete-item','item'=>'Movie Tags'),
      ));
      copy_admin_menu_item('Movies',array('Actors','Add New')); // Copy the 'Add New' over from Actors
      renamed_admin_menu_item('Movies','Add New','Add Actor');  // Rename copied Actor 'Add New' to 'Add Actor
      add_admin_menu_item('Movies',array(                       // (Another way to get a 'Add Actor' Link to a section.)
        'title' => 'Alt Add Actor ',
        'slug' => 'post-new.php?post_type=actor',
      ), array(// Add Back the Movie Tags at the end.
        'where'=>'end'
      ));
      add_admin_menu_item('Movies',$movie_tags_item_array,array(// Add Back the Movie Tags at the end.
        'where'=>'end'
      ));
      delete_admin_menu_section('Actors');                      // Finally just get rid of the actors section
    }
```

OR

Try this wordpress plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

[image: Working Plugin Snapshot]

Comment: Vaibs i used the admin menu editor plugin. Though i drag and drop the my plugins menu at a higher place at the vertical menu bar in the plugin actually it doesn't stay in that place.

Comment: I have tested in my local ..its working brilliantly ...@belekka